# How do I create a responsive carousel embedded card using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I was trying to create a Bootstrap card that has a 'slideshow' embedded. I want to use the other page to give more info about the first page. I was editing this on web and got to a fairly presentable product(https://gph.is/2NgOkWh) however when I tried it on my phone it was completely broken.

I attached the main code, leaving out the library links and some other default information.
Please let me know how I could correct this, I'd really appreciate it.

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem; height:24rem">
                    <div class="card-header text-muted">
                        App name
                    </div>
                    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!---------------------CARD BODY--------------------->
                            <!-- Indicators -->
                            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            </ul>


                            <!-- The slideshow -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner" style="height:15.2rem">

                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="sample.jpg"
                                         alt="Card image cap"
                                         id="sample">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                    <p class="card-text">Hi quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                                        the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                                </div>

                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text trewrwrwerwerwero build on the card
                                        title and make up
                                        the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!---------------------CARD BODY END--------------------->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer btn btn-primary">
                        Show me!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" ">
                <div class="card-header text-muted">
                    App name
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!---------------------CARD BODY--------------------->
                        <!-- Indicators -->
                        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        </ul>


                        <!-- The slideshow -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner" >

                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                        <img class="card-img-top" src="sample.jpg"
                                             alt="Card image cap"
                                             id="sample">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                        <p class="card-text">Hi quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                                            the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    
                                    </div>
    
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text trewrwrwerwerwero build on the card
                                            title and make up
                                            the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    
                                    </div>
                        <!---------------------CARD BODY END--------------------->

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer btn btn-primary">
                    Show me!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```